# Does Elasticsearch keep an order of multi-value fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

Does Elasticsearch keep an order of multi-value fields?

I.e. if I've put following values into fields:

```
{
    "values": ["one", "two", "three"],
    "values_original": ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

(Given that fields are not analyzed)

Can I be sure that the contents of lists will always be returned in the same order I put it there?

In the example above, I want to make sure that "one" on first position in "values" will always correspond to "1" in "values_original" etc.

I could keep it also as nested objects, i.e.

```
{
    "values": [
        {"original": "1", "new": "one"}, 
        {"original":"2", "new":"two"},
        {"original":"3","new":"three"}
    ]
}
```

but I want to avoid the overhead.

If it is guaranteed that order of values in multi-value field is preserved, then my approach of keeping two parallel multi-valued fields will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Elasticsearch - The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html) says the following:

> When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you indexed.
>
> However, arrays are indexed—made searchable—as multivalue fields, which are unordered. At search time, you can’t refer to “the first element” or “the last element.” Rather, think of an array as a bag of values.

So it seems that for stored fields order is preserved, for indexed fields it's not.

Answer (score 9):

I found out the answer.

Yes, I can rely on Elasticsearch to keep an order of values in multivalue field within a document. (However, when I am performing a search, there is no information available to Elasticsearch about at what position certain term was).

According to documentation:

> *When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field
>   that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you
>   indexed.*
>
> *However, arrays are indexed—made searchable—as multivalue fields, which are unordered. At search time, you can’t refer to “the first
>   element” or “the last element.” Rather, think of an array as a bag of
>   values.*

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#_multivalue_fields