# elasticsearch doc['...'] Arrays and order

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

i need to access document values stored in arrays from script. The order of the items in the array is important.

using doc['...'] to retrieve the array will mix up the order :-(

suppose a simple document like this

```
{
    "ar":[5,4,3,2,1]
}
```

retrieved using this Query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "match_all":{}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "values": {
      "script": {
        "inline":"return doc['ar']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will return the array in reversed(sorted) order: [1,2,3,4,5]
is there a way to prevent this behavior?

i can not resort to using _source because i need this in a "has_child" query, which does not support _source.

any ideas?

Comment: did your array output always coming in reversed order ?

Comment: No, allways sorted smallest to largest value:-(

Comment: What's your ElasticSearch version? I try it in my 2.3.3 version, the ar‘s values is in the reverse order, [5,4,3,2,1].

Comment: I'm on 5.4.0...

Comment: upgraded to 5.4.2, same problem...

Answer (score 3):

Need to know how Elasticsearch indexed an array field.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755389/does-elasticsearch-keep-an-order-of-multi-value-fields)

To make field searchable, array field will be indexed in order, and you can not get the first value in script like `doc['ar'][0]`

if you want the origin array with order, you can use `_source` to get it like `params._source['ar']`, the results will be `[5,4,3,2,1]`, but very slow than use `doc`

Comment: as i said, i can not resort to using _source because this is in a "has_child" query which does not support _source :-(

Comment: I solve this problem by another way. My array size is fixed, so I change array field to object like `ar = {'1': 5, '2': 4, ....}`. when return `doc['ar']` ,I can get values by turn with object keys

Comment: my arrays are not fixed, but this might work anyways. I'll give it a try.