# Elasticsearch: search in array in sequence

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a field `chunks` with `keyword` type which is just an a list of keyword. When I search through I do something like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "chunks": "chunk1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "chunks": "chunk2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I can retrieve all documents where there are both "chunk1" and "chunk2" inside the chunks field. However what if I care about the order? My solution is too have a script like

```
String[] chunks = doc['chunks'];
int c = 0;
String chunk = params.chunks[0];
for (int i = 0; i < chunks.length; ++i) {
  if (chunk == chunks[i]) {
    if (++c == params.chunks.length) {
      return true;
    }
    chunk = params.chunks[c];
  }
}
return false;
```

where params.chunks is something like `["chunk1", "chunk2"]`. The problem is the `doc['chunks']` [is unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755389/does-elasticsearch-keep-an-order-of-multi-value-fields?noredirect=1&lq=1), while `params._source` [isn't allowed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21188) from `_search` context.

It should be possible somehow, because Elastic itself has similar functionality for multitext search, so I can emulate the same field structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Elasticsearch keep an order of multi-value fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755389/does-elasticsearch-keep-an-order-of-multi-value-fields)

Comment: Of course, it doesn't. It's in the documentation.